# How do I share a function that modifies Redux state between multiple Components?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

My first thought is to create a Util file and export the function to all the Components.

The problem though is that the function involves a timed loop that needs to grab the most up to date State on every iteration.  So I cannot pass in part of the State needed as a parameter as it will not get the most updated State.. only the state as it was when I passed it in.

What is the best way I can accomplish this?  The function is called in 7 different places and involve heavy logic (calls other chains of functions) so copying and pasting all these functions in 7 different places is not ideal.

Thank you for any help

EDIT with some code:
EDIT2 removed some parts of code to make it easier to read

```
export function pageIn( compositionObj, pageObj, eActions, sActions, entitiesState, appState, aActions, playlist ) {
  // take page in
  let subcompObject = compositionObj.getSubcompositionById( pageObj.subComp.id );
  subcompObject.setPayload( pageObj.payload );
  subcompObject.playTo( 'In' );

  // if page has a duration, set a timer to take out at that specified time
  if ( pageObj.duration ) {
    let time = parseInt( pageObj.durationTime ) * 1000;
    let timerObj = undefined;

    if ( playlist.looped ) {
      timerObj = setTimeout(() => _getNextLoopedAction( compositionObj, pageObj, eActions, sActions, entitiesState, appState, aActions, playlist ), time);
    }
    else {
      timerObj = setTimeout(() => pageOut( compositionObj, pageObj, eActions, sActions ), time);
    }

    eActions.setPageProperty( pageObj.id, 'timer', timerObj, true );
  }
}

function _getNextLoopedAction( compositionObj, pageObj, eActions, sActions, entitiesState, appState, aActions, playlist ) {

  // THIS IS WHERE I WANT TO GRAB THE LATEST PLAYLIST AS THINGS MIGHT HAVE CHANGED, BUT IT ONLY GRABS THE OLD
  let playlistObj = entitiesState.playlistDict[ playlist.id ];
  let nextPageObj = _getNextPageWithDuration( pageObj, entitiesState, playlistObj );

  if ( nextPageObj ) {
    if (nextPageObj.id !== pageObj.id) {
      pageOut(compositionObj, pageObj, eActions, sActions);
    }

    if ( playlistObj.looped ) {
      pageIn(compositionObj, nextPageObj, eActions, sActions, entitiesState, appState, aActions, playlistObj);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you add some code to demonstrate? At a high level - sounds like you should have a dispatch of a shared action that multiple reducers respond to and multiple connected components update from (hard to discern from your initial question)

Comment: @GeoffreyAbdallah added some code to show you how i normally do things (those functions are in a Util file and I pass in Actions as parameters to call things and parts of the state).  Unfortunately doing it this way I cannot get the most up to date state on iteration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are:

- Modifying the redux state
- Doing async stuff
- Propagating to multiple components

A solution will be implementing your own [redux middleware](http://redux.js.org/docs/advanced/Middleware.html), they have examples of [implementations](http://redux.js.org/docs/advanced/Middleware.html#seven-examples) as well as [async actions](http://redux.js.org/docs/advanced/AsyncActions.html)

**This is an example of a `timeout` implementation in the redux cycle**

```
/**
 * Schedules actions with { meta: { delay: N } } to be delayed by N milliseconds.
 * Makes `dispatch` return a function to cancel the timeout in this case.
 */
const timeoutScheduler = store => next => action => {
  if (!action.meta || !action.meta.delay) {
    return next(action)
  }

  let timeoutId = setTimeout(
    () => next(action),
    action.meta.delay
  )

  return function cancel() {
    clearTimeout(timeoutId)
  }
}
```